# How to add trigonometric functions in calculator with infix postfix notation? java

Tags: java

What I want to do is a calculator, they asked me to create all the code and that I could only use libraries like the stack or queue, or Math, but I couldn't use libraries that already solve the exercise as a script, that's why I chose to use the infix PostFix notation, but in the end I don't know how I could add trigonometric functions

code:

```
import java.util.Stack;
public class InfixPostfixEvaluator
{
    private static final String operators = "-+/*^";
    private static final String operands = "0123456789";
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        InfixPostfixEvaluator infix = new InfixPostfixEvaluator();
        String a = "((1 + 2)^2 / (2 * 3)) + (2 ^ (1 / 2))";
        System.out.println("Result: " + infix.evalInfix(a));
    }
    public double evalInfix(String infix) 
    {
        return evaluatePostfix(convert2Postfix(infix));
    }
    public String convert2Postfix(String infixExpr)
    {
        char[] chars = infixExpr.toCharArray();
        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();
        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder(infixExpr.length());
        for (char c : chars) 
        {
            if (isOperator(c)) 
            {
                while (!stack.isEmpty() && stack.peek() != '(') 
                    if (operatorGreaterOrEqual(stack.peek(), c)) 
                        out.append(stack.pop());
                    else 
                        break;
                stack.push(c);
            }
            else if (c == '(') 
                stack.push(c);
            else if (c == ')') 
            {
                while (!stack.isEmpty() && stack.peek() != '(') 
                    out.append(stack.pop());
                if (!stack.isEmpty())
                    stack.pop();
            }
            else if (isOperand(c)) 
                out.append(c);
        }
        while (!stack.empty()) 
            out.append(stack.pop());
        return out.toString();
    }

    public double evaluatePostfix(String postfixExpr) 
    {
        char[] chars = postfixExpr.toCharArray();
        Stack<Double> stack = new Stack<Double>();
        for (char c : chars) 
        {
            if (isOperand(c)) 
                stack.push((double)(c - '0')); // convert char to int val
            else if (isOperator(c)) 
            {
                double op1 = stack.pop();
                double op2 = stack.pop();
                double result;
                switch (c)
                {
                    case '*':
                        result = op1 * op2;
                        stack.push(result);
                        break;
                    case '/':
                        result = op2 / op1;
                        stack.push(result);
                        break;
                    case '+':
                        result = op1 + op2;
                        stack.push(result);
                        break;
                    case '-':
                        result = op2 - op1;
                        stack.push(result);
                        break;
                    case '^':
                        result = Math.pow(op2, op1);
                        stack.push(result);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        return stack.pop();
    }
    private double getPrecedence(char operator) 
    {
        double ret = 0;
        if (operator == '-' || operator == '+')
            ret = 1;
        else if (operator == '*' || operator == '/') 
            ret = 2;
        else if (operator == '^')
            ret = 3;
        return ret;
    }
    private boolean operatorGreaterOrEqual(char op1, char op2) 
    {
        return getPrecedence(op1) >= getPrecedence(op2);
    }
    private boolean isOperator(char val) 
    {
        return operators.indexOf(val) >= 0;
    }
    private boolean isOperand(char val) 
    {
        return operands.indexOf(val) >= 0;
    }
}
```

It occurred to me to give special characters to cos, sen, tan as cos -> #, sin -> $, and tan -> % then it occurred to me to change this, where I write the operators that I will use:

```
private static final String operators = "-+/*^#$%";
```

and this is the string that more or less I want to evaluate, take into account that it must be resolved with any string:

```
String a = "((1 + 2)^2 / (2 * 3)) + #(2 ^ (1 / 2))";
```

it would be the same as writing:

```
String a = "((1 + 2)^2 / (2 * 3)) + cos(2 ^ (1 / 2))";
```

and finally where did the operations, I add a case let's say that # is the cos and I want it to solve it, but the truth is I don't know how:

```
public double evaluatePostfix(String postfixExpr) 
{
    char[] chars = postfixExpr.toCharArray();
    Stack<Double> stack = new Stack<Double>();
    for (char c : chars) 
    {
        if (isOperand(c)) 
            stack.push((double)(c - '0')); // convert char to int val
        else if (isOperator(c)) 
        {
            double op1 = stack.pop();
            double op2 = stack.pop();
            double result;
            switch (c)
            {
                case '*':
                    result = op1 * op2;
                    stack.push(result);
                    break;
                case '/':
                    result = op2 / op1;
                    stack.push(result);
                    break;
                case '+':
                    result = op1 + op2;
                    stack.push(result);
                    break;
                case '-':
                    result = op2 - op1;
                    stack.push(result);
                    break;
                case '^':
                    result = Math.pow(op2, op1);
                    stack.push(result);
                    break;
                case '#':
                    result = Math.cos(op1);
                    stack.push(result);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return stack.pop();
}
```

but it doesn't work like that at all.
Also tell them that if there was a way to write cos () directly in the form of a special character that I choose, it would help me much more.
Any clarification you want, tell me, thank you very much.

Comment: I think that the first thing you should do is to look at your operator *before* you pop your operands, and decide how many operands to pop for that particular operator. Maybe you could write an `isUnaryOperator` function, which would be similar to your `isOperator` function.

Comment: *It occurred to me to give special characters to cos, sen, tan as cos -> #, sin -> $, and tan -> %* You could do this inside your program.  In other words, change "cos" to "#" before you parse the String.  However, you will run out of special characters at some point.  Then @tgdavies' idea would be useful.

Comment: @tgdavies Could you be so kind as to show me how to abstract what you're saying? The truth is I am willing to change what you tell me but first I must understand you better and thank you very much

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc do not worry about that, I have no problems making the change in the strings, but what I need most now is to understand how I could do so that there are trigonometric operations in my calculator